# how to load large Ntriple data into jena tdb

Tags: jena, dbpedia

I'm using Dbpedia in my project and I wanted to create a local sparql end point as the online one is not reliable. I downloaded data dumps (large NT files) and decided to use Jena TDB. Using the NetBeans IDE am using an input stream to read in the source NT file and then using the following line of code to load the NT file into a datasetGraph:

```
 TDBLoader.load(indexingDataset, inputs, true);
```

I let it run for about 5 hrs now and it still isnt done. Whilst doing this everything on my laptop seems to slow down probably because of it taking all my physical memory space. Is there a faster way to do this???

The documentation says to use tdbloader2 but its only available for linux while am using windows. Would be really helpful if anyone could tel me how to use this tool in windows using cygwin. Please take into consideration I have never really used Cygwin in windows.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The latest release of TDB has two command line utilities for bulk loading: tdbloader and tdbloader2. The first is pure Java and it runs on Windows as well as on any machine with a JVM. The second is a mix of Java and UNIX shell script (in particular it uses UNIX sort). It runs on Linux, I am not sure it runs on Cygwin. I suggest you use tdbloader on a 64-bit machine with as much RAM as you can find. :-)

The latest release of TDB is available here:
http://www.apache.org/dist/incubator/jena/jena-tdb-0.9.0-incubating/jena-tdb-0.9.0-incubating-distribution.zip

The development version of TDB has an additional bulk loader command: tdbloader3. This is a pure Java version of tdbloader2. Instead of using UNIX sort (which works only on text files) we used a pure Java external sort with binary files. For more details on tdbloader3, search for the JENA-117 issue.

You can find a SNAPSHOT of TDB in the Apache snapshots repository, you are warned, that has not been released yet.

For the more adventurous there is also tdbloader4 which is not included in Apache Jena and it is to be considered an experimental prototype.
tdbloader4 builds TDB indexes (i.e. B+Tree indexes) using MapReduce (this is stretching a little bit the MapReduce model, but it works).
You can find tdbloader4 here: https://github.com/castagna/tdbloader4

To conclude, my advise to you, on Windows, is: download the latest official release of TDB and use tdbloader with a 64-bit machine with a lot of RAM. If you do not have one, use an m1.xlarge EC2 instance (i.e. 15 GB of RAM) (or equivalent).

For more help, I invite you to join the official jena-users@incubator.apache.org mailing list where, I am sure, you'll have better and faster support.

Comment: I'm currently using tdbloader2 to load ~120 million triples into TDB. It's pretty slow (8 hours+) and seems to slow down as the load progresses. Are their any benchmarks comparing tdbloader2, tdbloader3 and tdbloader4? Or is there any way to merge multiple TDB databases? Any advice would be appreciated.